# C# Reflection binding result Linq2Sql to list

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, reflection, binding

I am new using Reflection and after three days of searching I could not get a result. I would appreciate some help.

What I am trying to do is to bind the Result to a list.

I have a class:

```
public class DropdownList
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have a function:

```
public static List<DropdownList> getDropdownList(string Method)
{
    using (var Context = new WebDataContext())
    {
        var method = Context.GetType().GetMethod(Method);
        if (method == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Defined DataContext does not have method" + Method);

        var result = method.Invoke(Context,null);

        var toReturn = (from x in result select new DropdownList { ID = x.???, Description = x.??? }).ToList();

        return toReturn;
    } 
}
```

I bind this to a combobox:

```
StatuscomboBoxProperties.DataSource = getDropdownList("Get_SupplierList");
```

The "result" in the toReturn give the following error:

```
could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type "system.Reflection.MethodInfo' "Select" not found
```

My question is: If you hover over result there is a Result View and I can see the data that returned from the method but how will I bind my list the that data.

Comment: `Invoke` returns an `object`. So result is an `object`. You should know a common base type (or interface) and cast the result of `method.Invoke` to it. I also think you should find another way to do it because using reflection is not appropriate in your case.

Comment: No, you don't want to use Reflection here. If you're amenable to an alternate solution, let me know and I'll whip up a demo using delegates.

Comment: Any alternative solution will do. It is important that I pass the method as a string as I have build a framework that control the look and feel of my grids (devexpress) from a stand alone executable. This is my last step to bind the dropdown lists to comboboxes in the grid where required.

Comment: Forgot to add you to my comment @ChrisHardie Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my approach and my application is working great. Any comment or advice on my new approach will be appreciated.

I kept my class:

```
public class DropdownList
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I changed my function to:

```
public static List<DropdownList> getDropdownList(string Method)
{
    using (var Context = new WebDataContext())
    {
        var toReturn = Context.ExecuteQuery<DropdownList>("EXEC " + Method).ToList();
        return toReturn;
    } 
}
```

I bind this to a combobox:

```
StatuscomboBoxProperties.DataSource = getDropdownList("Get_SupplierList");
```

The "Get_SupplierList" are passed in by a combobox.